# Get data from EditText from Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, interface

I need to pass String data from `EditTexts` from `Fragment` to `Activity`, I know that I have to use `interface`. But I still have the same error (`Null Object`). Can you tell me how to fix it? Here is my code:

`Main Activity`

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements fragment_intro_activity_2.OnDataPass {

    Button button_intro;
    EditText et;
    boolean showingFirst;
    String wynik;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        button_intro = findViewById(R.id.button_intro);
        et = findViewById(R.id.edOperetka);

     FullScreencall();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_contrainer_intro,
                new fragment_intro_activity_1()).commit();

       showingFirst = true;


       button_intro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               if(showingFirst==true){
                   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_contrainer_intro,
                           new fragment_intro_activity_2()).commit();
                   showingFirst = false;
               }else {
//
//                   Toast.makeText(IntroActivity.this, "123123",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   wynik = et.getText().toString();
            onDataPass(wynik);
               }
           }
       });
    }
```

`Fragment`

```
public class fragment_intro_activity_2 extends Fragment {

    View v;
    OnDataPass dataPasser;


    public fragment_intro_activity_2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_intro_activity_2, container, false);
        return v;
    }
    public interface OnDataPass {
         void onDataPass(String data);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        dataPasser = (OnDataPass) context;
    }
    public void passData(String data) {
        dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
    }

}
```

`Logcat`

```
Process: com.example.wynagrodzeniedodatkowe, PID: 32263
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.wynagrodzeniedodatkowe.IntroActivity$1.onClick(IntroActivity.java:54
```

And this 54 line is this: `wynik = et.getText().toString();`

Comment: post your `logcat` error

Comment: @Swati - I added it in question

Comment: Is the edittext inside your fragment?

Comment: Yes Sir. I tried to do it in fragment (`String wynik = et.v.findVievbyId(ID`). But I dont know how to pass the data to Button(its in Activity)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logcat message, it tells me that the following line

```
findViewById(R.id.edOperetka)
```

Returns null so make sure that the ID is created correctly in the XML and references correctly from the code (that it's the same ID).

If you wan't to retrieve the EditText inside your fragment you can do the following.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_intro_activity_2, container, false);

    EditText et = v.findViewById(R.id.edOperetka);

    return v;
}
```

Now you can retrieve the text from as you did before.

Comment: How to make reference to EditText from Fragment in Activity?

Comment: @Formaxinho In onCreateView(...) you can call v.findViewById(...).

Comment: Thanks Ludvig, I can do it on the Fragment. But how to gettext grom EditText. I think that I should learn more about interfaces but od you have clue for my problem please tell me.